# Can't establish connection to SQLServer with Google Apps Script via JDBC

Tags: sql-server, google-apps-script, jdbc

I'm trying to establish the connection to my computer's local SQL Server using the following command:

`var conn = Jdbc.getConnection('jdbc:sqlserver://<url>;databaseName=<db>','<user>','<pw>');`

However, I get the following error:

> Unexpected error while getting the method or property getConnection on
> object Jdbc

Can anybody please help me?

Comment: Have you checked how to use it with the [JDBC guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc)? Also, can you provide more information on the error or have you tested it with a public db?

Comment: Hi Kessy, thanks for your reply. I actually copy various code from other stackedoverflow answered, and they all have the following code. No I haven't tried to test with a public DB, I'm new to google appscript and there are not many guide out there. Can you please explain how to test with a public DB?

Comment: you can find on google multiple public databases you can use to try your code by searching "public mysql database" and get the connection details to test it.